# Is there a way to navigate to other view from CanActivate?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have create following annotation:

```
@CanActivate(
(next,prev)=> {
    var neededPermission = ["PERMISSION"];
    var userPermissions = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('permissions'));
    if (userPermissions && !_.isEmpty(_.intersection(userPermissions, neededPermission))) {
        return true
    }else {
//Navigate to No Permission state?
        return false;
    }
}
```

)

And I am wondering how I can navigate user to other page, if the result of the funcition is `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zoSAcCkAwQ1TfzxJaiSI?p=preview) linked to in [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-139381970) shows how this can be done

The `Protected` component has a `@CanActivate(...)` decorator that calls `isLoggedIn()` which calls `router.navigate()`.

This Plunker demonstrates how to use DI in `@CanActivate()`